# choose which installation to use

Tags: version

I want to use a program called `samtools`. It is installed by default but I want to use another installation. The default is in: `/usr/bin/samtools`

I want to use `./samtools-1.14/samtools`. How do I change this without deleting the bin version?

Comment: Did you build the other version (1.14) yourself?

Comment: Yes, that I did